# how to convert GMT to selected locatuion time

Tags: php

I have a date in  `GMT is 2013-07-06 05:54:45` i need to convert this to `GMT +3:00 Hours`

for example

```
$my_GMT_date_time = '2013-07-06 05:54:45'; //it is `GMT +0:00 Hours`
```

i need to convert this local `$my_GMT_date_time` in to  `GMT +3:00 Hours` include with daylight saving

How to do this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first set the default time zone to be GMT, then use `DateTimeZone` to convert to the expected time zone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-07-06 05:54:45');
$nairobi_time = new DateTimeZone('Africa/Nairobi');
$datetime->setTimezone($nairobi_time);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: what about the daylight saving (I)?